# Modify all buttons text size programmatically?

Tags: android, view

I need to change the text color of all buttons in a view programmatically.

Right now I'm modifying them one by one like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_dialer, container, false);

    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button0);
    b.setTextColor(value);

    b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setTextColor(value);
```

But since there are a lot of buttons I want to modify them all at once? How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all children of your layout, checking if next view is instance of Button or its subclass:

```
ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
int count = viewgroup.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
    View view = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof Button){
        (Button)view.setTextColor(value);
    }
}
```

This will work if your buttons lays on the same level. Otherwise you need to build a recurrent function similar to this:

```
public void setNewColor(View view, int value){
    if (view instanceof Button){
        ((Button) view).setTextColor(value);
    }
    else if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        int count = viewgroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
            View viewNext = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
            setNewColor(viewNext, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and apply it to your layout:

```
setNewColor(findViewById(R.id.your_layout), your_color);
```

Comment: Hi Salauyou, I think you provided the best solution but I'm having problems implementing it. I just edited your answer to show you what I tried. I gave my main LinearLayout the id "container". Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: write `instanceof` instead of `instance of`, it's my stupid mistake ) and `getChildCount()` instead of `getchildcount()` sorry I don't have an access to eclipse now

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't modify the color or other property of layout elements in a view at once. You have to do how you are doing, i.e. set the color one by one.

However, you can create a button style in style.xml and assign the syle to all buttons and whenever you will change style.xml it will effect all the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You may have to iterate over all the views, and change colors of the buttons. [Check this page](http://android-wtf.com/2013/06/how-to-easily-traverse-any-view-hierarchy-in-android/) for how to traverse all child view / view groups of your layout, **including views (button) that are not direct children of your main layout**

Including the two classes provided, you will write easy code like:

```
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
List<Button> buttons = Views.find(root, Button.class);
for (Button b: buttons)
     b.setTextColor(value);
```